# openmp reduction does not provide the same answer as the sequential methodd

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, race-condition

I am trying to parallelize a vector dot product program using OpenMP. The following code shows what I did.

```
#define N 1000000

float dotProduct = 0;
float vector1Host[N], vector2Host[N]; //each element in the vectors are initialized to a value between 1 and 2

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)  reduction(+:dotProduct)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                dotProduct += vector1Host[i] * vector2Host[i];
```

The answer I get here is slightly different than what I get when I do the multiplication sequentially. Further, when I remove the `reduction(+:dotProduct)` and calculate the multiplications of each item seperately and add them together later (sequentially) I get the same answer as the completely sequential method.

```
float productComponents[N];

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            productComponents[i] += vector1Host[i] * vector2Host[i];

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
     dotProduct += productComponents[i];
```

The issue with this method is the performance. Please help me in finding the error in the first method, or an alternative method with good performance.

Update:
I added the output from a sample run.

N=1000000: Ans=2251335.750000: Time(ms)=2.59163  //sequential
N=1000000: Ans=2251356.750000: Time(ms)=0.65846  //openmp

Comment: *Slightly different?*

Comment: Also, for the record: the **bottom** one is correct?

Comment: @erip I added the answers from a sample run
and, yes, the bottom one gives an identical answer to the sequential one.

Comment: @erip: machine precision for float is about 1e-7, so the error here is perfectly consistent with that. If you need more accuracy use double, which gives you 1e-15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point operations are not commutative. Therefore it is possible that your code is giving differing and possibly unpredictable results based on the order in which the floats are added to the accumulating variable.

Openmp due to the nature of parallelising the code results in the additions being performed in an arbitrary order and thus causes slightly unpredictable value due to the above non commutative behaviour of floats.

Either you need to accept this unpredictability or serialise the additions.

The other option would be to use a fixed point library which was able to guarantee commutative addition, in which case the answer would be predictable regardless of the resulting order of the additions.

Comment: I think that is the reason. So based on this, the answer I get with the serial method is not necessarily correct as well, right? Because it is just one permutation of how the values can be added.

Comment: @rajeerc In essence, floats, due to not being a perfect representation of real numbers lose accuracy with each operation, and the order of the additions effects exactly how much accuracy they lose due to how they are represented. The serial method will be predictable and give the same answer each time, but not necessarily the most accurate one.

Comment: Floating point numbers prove the existence of (your favorite Deity/Deities here) by negation as they are clearly the invention of (your favorite Personification of Evil here). Note: if you're an atheist you can apply Religious Algebra: the (Deity) and (Personification of Evil) cancel out, allowing us to rotate the proposition through the metaphysical plane, and following an appropriate Logical translation we arrive at the not-unexpected result of "Sh*t happens" / "Deal with it". WARNING: continent-spanning wars have been fought over more trivial results than this. KIDS! DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME!

Comment: and another option is to use Kahan sumation. This operations i memory bandwidth bound so you might as well give the CPU something to do as it waits for main memory.